# Building a dashboard in Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have used Shiny for R and specifically the Shinydashboard package to build easily navigatable dashboards in the past year or so. I have recently started using the Python, pandas, etc ecosystem for doing data analysis. I now want to build a dashboard with a number of inputs and outputs. I can get the functionality up running using Dash, but defining the layout and look of the app is really time consuming compared to using the default layout from the shinydashboard's package in R.

The convenience that Shiny and Shinydashboard provides is:

- Easy layout of components because it is based on Bootstrap
- A quite nice looking layout where skinning is build in.
- A rich set of input components where the label/title of the input is bundled together with the input.

My question is now this:

- Are there any extensions to Dash which provides the above functionality, or alternatively some good examples showing how to do the above?

Comment: I wrote a dashboard package for python called [bowtie](https://github.com/jwkvam/bowtie). I don't know if it satisfies the requirements you are thinking, it comes with captions and it's layout is based on css grid. If you are interested, I'm happy to chat more about your use cases.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar experience. A lot said python is more readable, while I agree, however, I don't find it as on par with R or Shiny in their respective fields yet.

Comment: Lasse, can I ask a question regarding why you are switching from R and Shiny to Python and Dash? I did that because team members think Python is more readable and have seen some bad R code before, which I agree that R is very flexible and as a result can be written in a way that is difficult to maintain

Comment: Actually the reason is the same for me. I am part of a team with mainly software developers and they prefer to maintain Python code compared to R code. I tend to agree with the developers that Python is an easier to maintain lanugage and also hosting a Dash application is much easier than a Shiny application since Dash is based on Flask. On the other hand I really like the tidyverse and Shiny, so it is a bit of a tradeof.